# How to put a function inside event.respondWith() in javascript that returns a response

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I have a service worker that should return a cached file if it's of a certain type. If not, it should fetch the resource. I put the code that checks if the file is a certain type inside the fetch function. If it is, it returns the cached version. If not, it returns the fetched version. I have found out though, that it sends a network request for the fetch, then returns the cached version (duh).

I don't want this because it undos the purpose of serving the cached version of a large file instead of fetching it if possible. I realized I have to put the if then statement outside of the fetch, but that would mean that I am putting it in as a parameter. This is a problem, because it throws an error. So, I decided to put it inside a function. This returns an invalid response, so I don't know what I am doing wrong. It must be that the function inside the event.respondWith() must not be returning, but why?

My code is:

```
this.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
    event.respondWith(function(){
        //if the event request is a music file (I have it stored in a folder named music, so if the request is like "music/musicfile.mp3"), then returned the cached version. If not, fetch the file over the network. 
        if(event.request.url.match(/music\//)){
            return caches.match(event.request).then(function(r){
                if(r){
                    return r;
                }
                else{
                    return fetch(event.request).then(function(fetchR){
                        return fetchR;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            return fetch(event.request).then(function(res){
                return res;
            }).catch(function(){
                return caches.match(event.request).then(function(cacheRes){
                    if(cacheRes){
                        return cacheRes;
                    }
                    else{
                        return new Response("Error",{status : 520, statusText : "Error fetching cache", headers :new Headers({"Content-Type":"text/html"})});
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
    );
});
```

I know this is probably not the best approach, but if there is another way I would gladly like to improve it for best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this. Since event.respondWith() takes a response, not a function, if you give it a function it treats that as a response, it doesn't run it. What you have to do is call an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), that way your function gets executed and returns a response). IIFE syntax:

```
(function{
   console.log("I was run immediately after I was created!");
})();
```